# Android Starter kits

Tags: android

I would like to build an Android application that works with online database. The SQL server is hosted by the same webhost that hosts my website. Now I want the Android app to be able to access it. I heard there is a starter kit for app of this type. Can anyone provide more info about it or direct me to a step by step article?

Thanks.

Comment: i heard for the first time about "starter kit", yes there are "Samples" provided with each API level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First checkout the android sdk at http://developer.android.com  Check out their tutorials as it will help you learn the API.

You will then need to be able to write some server side code because AFAIK, the only database android can talk to out of the box is SQLignt.  I found this tutorial after a quick google search on how to send JSON objects to your server, and have PHP write it to the database: http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/connecting-mysql-database